# Class Library, .NET 3.1 core : Error CS5001 Program does not contain a static Main Method

Tags: c#, .net-core

I realize that similar questions have various answers, however in my case I have a .net Core 3.1 project and my project is a Class Library, so why is the compiler requesting me to have a Main entry point?  The answers in other questions basically suggest to use Class Library, but that does not seem to work on .net Core 3.1

[image]

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<RootNamespace>Tutorials_UnitTest</RootNamespace>
<IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
<GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
</PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
 <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers ;buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
 </PackageReference>
 <PackageReference Include="coverlet.msbuild" Version="3.1.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.16.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="..\Tutorials\Tutorials.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

NOTE:  I have tried clean rebuild,  restarting Visual Studio, deleting all /bin, /obj directories, but still fails.

Comment: Might help if you include full .csproj file contents

Comment: Yeah probably something wrong in the .csproj file - can you post it?

Comment: ok I have  added it,  I never edit this directly though...

Comment: Maybe remove that strange empty "StartupObject" tag.

Comment: @Evk  I removed ApplicationIcon and StartupObject tags (will update the xml in question)  but still fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the unit test framework packages:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.3.0">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers ;buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="coverlet.msbuild" Version="2.9.0">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.16.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Specifically, it's the `"coverlet.collector"` that causes the issue.

If your library is NOT a unit test library (which it appears it is not) then just remove that entire `<ItemGroup>`.

Otherwise, you can fix it by adding the following to the `<PropertyGroup>` part of the project file:

```
<GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
```

Comment: I added <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile> and it still fails.  you may be right however about the coverlet.  The issue is that this IS a unit test project and I absolutely need the coverlet reference as we use it for coverage analysis in our local builds and on devops.  I have used it regularly in other projects and it works.  I updated my question with <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile> added to the xml.

Comment: @shelbypereira Did you force a rebuild using Build|Rebuild All after changing the project file?

Comment: As a further improvement, I also updated coverlet collector and msbuild to the latest version 3.1.0, still no luck.  Is it possible there is a caching issue somewhere?  Something I have  to manually delete to fix the build issue?

Comment: yes,  just checked again with a rebuild all, but fails.

Comment: You might need to delete all temp files. If that still doesn't work, I can only assume it's something to do with `<ProjectReference Include="..\Tutorials\Tutorials.csproj" />`

Comment: thanks your pointer to the included project helped me find the issue.  The referenced project was being compiled with <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>   .  I moved my unit test project to netstandard2.0 and it works now.